# Fetching multiple records from MAX mysql keyword?

Tags: mysql

I have only one table with the name of offers and it has multiple offers in it like each time we pull in an offer, we create a new row for example: for travelling to Timbuktu, there can be 10 or more rows each containing an offer, each time a offers comes in, it is being saved with PHP unix timestamp in the column name 'created_on', so to figure out which offer is latest, I am currently using following query:

> SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE city= 'Timbuktu' AND created_on=(SELECT max(created_on)from offers WHERE city = 'Timbuktu')

This serves the purpose if I have to fetch only one latest row, if say I want to fetch last 4 or 8 rows with the greatest timestamp, how I can do that in most efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM offers
WHERE city= 'Timbuktu'
order by created_on desc
limit 0, 8
```

and for 1 row you can use same request just replace 8 with 1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM offers WHERE city='Timbuktu' ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 4;
```